# Unable to change the Flash microphone settings

Tags: flash, settings, microsoft

I want to find out the name of a song by singing or humming it on Midomi.

I follow these steps:

1. I go on the website «www.midomi.com»;
2. I click on the area «Click and Sing or Hum»: a message appears saying «You must first "Allow" permissions in "Microphone Settings" to use Voice Search» and showing the button «Microphone Setting»;
3. I left-click on the button: nothing happens; I right-click on it: a menu containing the entry «Global settings...» shows;
4. I click on the entry: the «Adobe Flash Player Preferences» appears;
5. I click on the tab «Camera and Mic», then on the button «Camera and Microphone Settings by Site...»: a new window opens;
6. I save «www.midomi.com» and «midomi.com» as «Allow», then exit.

Nonetheless, the problem is not resolved: I can't sing or hum the song as the microphone settings message is still there.

My system:

– OS: Ubuntu 12.10 desktop 32 bit;

– WWW browser: Firefox 17.0.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug not allowing to modify Flash settings through the normal settings.

There is a solution though. Go to the [Global Storage Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html) and make the changes you need (allowing the site) through there.

Then visit the www.midomi.com site again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For others having problems with Flash using Firefox, using Google Chrome solved the problem for me. Firefox seems to work particularly badly with Flash on Linux.