# Microphone recording through flashplayer on Ubuntu

Tags: flash, microphone, audio-recording

My USB headset and my USB webcam are functioning normally. I can use Skype without any problem. However, even when I allow Flash to [record through my webcam and microphone](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/fr/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html),
 still I can't record my voice over the mic in any Flash app. Video through the webcam and sound output in the headset are ok.

I have read the following posts, but there was no useful answer:

- [Unable to change the Flash microphone settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232080/unable-to-change-the-flash-microphone-settings)
- [Is there no support for microphone recording in Flash Player for linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240285/is-there-no-support-for-microphone-recording-in-flash-player-for-linux/240291#240291)

Answer (score 2):

Some users on my corporate network had this problem, too. There was no audio from microphone when they were accessing the flash based chat room at [Englishtown](http://www.englishtown.com/).

I "solved" it by using Google Chrome. Its built-in flash player had no problem recording audio from microphone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Firefox does seem to have some inherent problems with Flash and using Chrome allowed the microphone to work, even in 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the mic recording in flash on the sites like tinychat.com.

1. Go to tinychat.com
2. On the site press green button 'Instant chat room' than click 'Enter
   Room'
3. Wait for flash app to load, press 'guess' button and put your nick
   in there. You are in the app, now
4. To check the mic out, just press 'Start Broadcasting'
5. Set the hardware in flash settings that should be in the middle of
   the app. Allow your mic and cam to be accessed by flash
6. Pick 'Microphone Only'
7. Select the microphone, press continue, 'open microphone' and finish.
8. In Ubuntu's sound setting make sure the mic is selected as input and that it is not muted.

If sound is recording you can see it on small colorful vu sound level indicator in the lower left corner of your black square with your nick. Check other chats too see how it looks like, you will see.

I myself have a mic working in Skype and most linux audio applications I use, but my laptops HDA Intel does not work as mic in flash sound recording apps. Flash shows the card but no sound is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the `pavucontrol` package, and run the command of the same name, you should see an entry for *ALSA Plug-in* under the *Recording* tab, once you open the web page with the flash object in question that is requesting to record. You can then click the button which shows your sound card's name, to the right of that heading, and select your USB headset as the input device.

Or, alternatively, on the *Input Devices* tab, you can click the "default" button (last one to the right in collection of three buttons for mute/lock channels/default to the right) for your USB headset, before running the web browser and opening the page. This should result in the plug-in defaulting to that device for recording.

Comment: Pavucontrol is installed, but there is no Flash application running under the Recording tab (all streams diplay) when the Web page with the Flash content is supposed to record.

Comment: The alternative did not succeed either. The third button is (in French) "définir comme alternative" (set as alternative). Does not seem like "default"... Could be a translation issue, though.

Comment: Since sound request is addressed to Alsa, wouldn't it help to use `alsamixer` rather than `pavucontrol`? However, I do not see how to fix the issue with the command line `alsamixer`

Comment: Can you link me to a Flash Web page where I could test my mic settings? My current issue is with an eLearning interface (private access).

Comment: I don't know of any flash sites that require a microphone. When I go to YouTube, the *ALSA Plug-in* appears under the *Playback* tab, and I can direct its output elsewhere. I would expect the same behavior for recording. If it doesn't work, I an only guess that Flash isn't actually trying to record. If there was an easily usable flash app to test with that I could use, I could test here though. From what you've said though, I'd say it's not trying to record.